# Jasper Designer and BigQuery JDBC driver: unable to execute query with some keywords

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, google-bigquery

I am using ***Jaspersoft iReport Designer*** 5.0.0 and bqjdbc-0.1.jar ([a **BigQuery JDBC Driver**](http://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc)) and I want to associate a query to a new report.

I currently have some problems when creating a new report with a query that has the keywords '***count***' or '***as***'. If I don't put these keywords my query works correctly.

What I find strange is that my problematic query will work if I select "Execute Command..." from my database connection in the Services window.

I also had the same problem with Jasper 4.8. I am not sure if the problem is with the BigQuery driver or with Jasper.

The error that I get when I try to associate the query to a new report is the following:

```
Message:
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: General problem: null

Check username and password; is the DBMS active ?!
Level: SEVERE
Stack Trace:
General problem: null Check username and password; is the DBMS active ?!        
 com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.data.fieldsproviders.SQLFieldsProvider.getFields(SQLFieldsProvider.java:172) 
 com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.connection.JDBCConnection.readFields(JDBCConnection.java:472)
 com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.wizards.ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.validate(ConnectionSelectionWi    zardPanel.java:146)
 org.openide.WizardDescriptor$7.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1357)
 org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
 org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is interesting, could you give us an example of your query?

For me it seems that iReport wants to read something that isn't there.

The bigger problem is, that our logger doesn't really likes the iReport, but if you could check your log that would be a big help for us. For more information about the logging:
http://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/wiki/Logger

In the current 0.1 version we don't do anything with the query, just pass it to BigQuery. So if your query runs fine on the BigQuery Browser Tool, it should run fine with the Driver too.

Also, we don't really check stackoverflow, so please post your problems here, since we can answer your questions faster, over there:

http://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/issues/entry